compiler.runtime.customInstaller fails to reduce mcr installer size
I have a matlab toolbox, with a single-window GUI. I was able to build it mcc/deploytool to create a standalone 7MB executable. However, I was not happy for the installer size, as the R2016 matlab runtime is 700MB in size, 100x larger than my application.
When I saw a new matlab compiler API compiler.runtime.customInstaller coming with R2024b is cable of creating smaller MCR installer including only needed files, I was very happy and immediately tried it, however, the result was disappointing.
The installer bundled with MCR in R2024b for my app build by deploytool - without using the customInstaller - is 1.2GB in size (another 2x increase in size compared to the already large package generated by R2016). Then, when I called
results = compiler.build.standaloneApplication("myapp.m");
compiler.runtime.customInstaller("myapp_installer", results, 'RuntimeDelivery', 'installer');

however, the generated package has the same 1.2GB in size. I have followed the help page of compiler.runtime.customInstaller
https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/compiler.runtime.custominstaller.html
did I miss anything? why customInstaller fails to trim the installer size? my app only use basic matlab features.
the requiredMCRProducts.txt file shows that I only need the following MCR components

'MATLAB Runtime - Core'
'MATLAB Runtime - Graphics'
'MATLAB Runtime - Non Interactive MATLAB'
'MATLAB Runtime - Numerics'
'MATLAB Runtime - Image Processing Toolbox Addin'


I have also posted this question in MATLAB's forum
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2162625-compiler-runtime-custominstaller-fails-to-reduce-mcr-installer-size
from the reply by Sumukh, it appears that compiler.runtime.customInstaller is basically doing the same as deploytool, that creates a "reduce-sized" mcr package using only the components returned by requiredMCRProducts.txt. It is simply an API version of this function - one should not expect further mcr file size reduction by calling this API.
Because of this, the mcr local installer is the best matlab can produce, it is rather a coarse-grained reduction based on the components, but it currently does not support fine-grained file-level trimming.
